# Is there a plugin for parsing and integrating Matlab in Sonarqube?

Tags: matlab, sonarqube, sonarqube-5.0, sonarqube5.1, sonarqube-4.5

1. Does someone know, where I can find a plugin for parsing and integrating Matlab

   in Sonarqube ?
2. If I have got or written this plugin, can I use the internal PMD runner of Sonarqube to check created Custom Rules (XPath) for Matlab ?

   Or do I have to write an extra "parser" for extending PMD with
   Matlab ?

Thank you very much in advance!

---

**EDIT**

*Okay, I am still thinking about it. Like it seems, I have to write/extend a matlab grammar, if I want to use PMD (with JavaCC I can generate parser and lexer).*

But before I do this, can I also generate parser and lexer for Sonarqube with the created grammar and a generator (e.g. ANTLR) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no Matlab plugin for SonarQube.

If you decide to develop the plugin yourself (which is not a small undertaking), then you will not need PMD. Have a look at the PHP or CSS plugins source code to know how to get started:

- https://github.com/SonarCommunity/sonar-php
- https://github.com/SonarCommunity/sonar-css

Alternatively, you can also add support of the Matlab language to PMD, and then develop a SonarQube "Matlab PMD" plugin. This does **not** make sense, unless you really want to be integrated with PMD for some reason. There seems currently to be **very limited** Matlab support in PMD http://pmd.sourceforge.net/pmd-5.3.2/pmd-matlab/index.html - i.e. just a lexer, but no parser nor rules.

Comment: Thanks, then I try to find the easiest solution as possible.

Comment: I have edited my question and wait for an answer. Thank you in advance.